# Building Android User Interface

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Basically I'm just starting out with Android development (though I have a fairly extensive Java background) and I'm having difficulty working out how I could build this user interface where the components move in (like the arrows indicate) in this order:

The bottom image moves upwards and then stops
The first image moves right and over the top of the bottom image
The image below this moves left over the top of the bottom image
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1wou.png

I've been really pulling my hair out about how I could do this and I've read the API fairly extensively for a solution because its clearly a simple problem but I honestly cant work it out. One of my main problems is I'm not sure which layout manager to use!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the animation framework for this. I've not used it extensively, but I should be able to point you in the right direction.

First off, just create the layout in the 'after' position, i.e. a linear layout with two buttons. Fiddle with the styles until it looks right.

When your activity loads, you're going to hide each of these views (visibility=false) and then show each one and apply an animation to each in sequence. The key is that each animation will start off-screen. This is the part that I'm not sure how to implement, but try looking at android animation examples to see how to move views around.

Hope this helps :)